# gdb not launching app

Tags: shell, gdb

I am trying to run a app using gdb in emulator shell. I use following command

```
gdb <path of exe>
```

However, The app does not launch and I get following error

```
Starting program: <path of exe>
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Program exited normally.
```

However, when I attach a running process to gdb, it works fine.

```
gdb -pid <process_id>
```

What could be the reason?

```
****<Update>****
On Employed Russian's advice, I did these steps
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb40
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 2 at 0xc43
(gdb) catch syscall exit
Catchpoint 3 (syscall 'exit' [1])
(gdb) catch syscall exit_group
Catchpoint 4 (syscall 'exit_group' [252])

(gdb) r
Starting program: <Exe Path>
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, 0x80000b40 in _start ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x80000c43 in main ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Catchpoint 4 (call to syscall 'exit_group'), 0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall
    ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

What does **Catchpoint 4 (call to syscall 'exit_group'), 0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall**
this mean?

I probed further and i found this

```
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
__libc_start_main (main=0xb6deb030 <main>, argc=1, ubp_av=0xbffffce4, 
    init=0x80037ab0 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=0x80037b10 <__libc_csu_fini>, 
    rtld_fini=0xb7ff1000 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0xbffffcdc) at libc-start.c:258
258 libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
    in libc-start.c
```

However, libc.so is present and i have exported its path also using

```
export LD_LIBRARY=$LD_LIBRARY:/lib
```

Why is not loading?

Comment: Could you tell something about your `executable` (libraries it links to ...)?  What's the OS?

Comment: It links to my own shared libs.Trying on linux

Comment: And those shared libs are linked to other libs on the system?  Which ones?

Comment: yes, to libc and other sys. libs

Comment: See if preloading those libs helps.

Comment: @devnull: Its already preloaded.

Comment: Let us know the exact command you are using to invoke gdb.

Answer (score 1):

> The app does not launch and I get following error

You are mistaken: the app **does** launch (and the output you get is *not* an error), and then immediately exits with `0` exit status.

Therefore, you should look at the problem with the app, not a problem with GDB. One way to look at the problem is to set a breakpoint on `_start` and `main`, and check whether either of these functions is reached.

If they are, using `catch syscall exit` or `catch syscall exit_group` may give you a clue for why the application exits.

Perhaps your application employs anti-reverse-engineering techniques, and detects that it is being debugged?

Update:

you've verified that the application in fact starts, reaches main, and then calls `exit`. Now all you have to do is figure out *why* it calls exit. The way to do that is to find out where `exit_group` system call is coming from.

And to do that, you should get to that system call (`Catchpoint 4`), issue GDB `where` command. That will tell you how your application decides to exit.

You also (apparently) built your application without debugging info (usually `-g` flag). You'll make your debugging easier if you build a debug version of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my question. I did the steps you advised. Can you please check the question?